# Google Apps Script Missing ) after for-loop control. (line 4, file "Code")Dismiss

Tags: google-apps-script

After running this script

```
    function followUpUnreplied() {
  // Every thread in your Inbox that is read, older than two days, and not labeled "delete me".
  var threads = GmailApp.search('label:leads---dealt-with older_than:1d newer_than:2d -{label:Conversion}');
  for (var i = 0; i &lt; threads.length; i++) {
    if (threads[i].getMessageCount() &lt; 2) {
    // looks like an unreplied-to message
      threads[i].addLabel(GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("Follow Up"))
    }
  }
}
```

I receive the error message

```
Missing ) after for-loop control. (line 4, file "Code")Dismiss
```

I'm not a programmer - just code monkey stuff. Anyone help me out on this? Any help much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `&lt;` with `<` and please mind that there are 2 occurences -- one in the `for` statement and one in the inner `if` statement.